Rambam and Minhagim
Going through Mishneh Torah, it is clear that Rambam brings down relatively few minhagim (especially as compared to the Tur and Shulchan Aruch etc). What determines whether or not Rambam will codify a Minhag in the Mishneh Torah? I can't find a common denominator.

Can you include some examples? Minhagim are often local and Rambam was writing to a universal audience.
